# Internet explorer throwing Object doesnt support property or method with JQuery

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm assuming this is pretty obvious but I can't work it out for myself. I'm using the Facebook javascript API to allow a user to login into a page I made. The following javascript throws the error Object doesnt support this property or method. IE is saying the first line is throwing the error. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
document.getElementById('auth-loginlink').addEventListener('click', function () {
            FB.login(function (response) {

            }, {scope: 'email,user_likes,read_stream'});
```

The page can be accessed on http://claritytrec.ucd.ie:9000/signup

Comment: That doesn't look like jQuery to me.

Comment: It's a copy paste job from the Facebook SDK.

Comment: Hey, you're the one who said _"My script ability is copy paste."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running your page in Quirks -mode. There must not be any characters or blank lines before declaring document type.

Only IE >= 9 knows `addEventListener()`, use `attachEvent()` instead with older IEs. [attachEvent in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28VS.85%29.aspx), you can find more information about the legacy eventhandling model of IE by following left-side links at the MSDN page.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea what I should be using instead of addEventListener? My script ability is copy paste.

Comment: @steve have you considered using jQuery?

Comment: I can use JQuery if needed. Is there a jquery call that would help me avoid these types of mishaps?

Comment: @steve since you are looking for legacy support, then yes absolutely. jQuery will normalize simple things like adding a click handler across multiple platforms.